# Creating a contact group from a local file to use with mu4e

Tags: email, mu4e, csv

I have a file `~/foo/contacts.csv` whose first two columns look like

```
Student ID,Student Name
firstID@foo.org,"Lennon, John"
secondID@foo.org,"McCartney, Paul"
thirdID@foo.org,"Harrison, George"
fourthID@foo.org,"Starr, Ringo"
```

In actuality, the file has dozens of lines and several other columns. This file is updated every day (people are added and others are deleted).

I'd like to be able to e-mail every person on this list using [mu4e](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/mu4e). Ideally this would be done so that each recipient cannot see the identities of the other receipts.

Does `mu4e` have the capability to read my csv file so I can easily email the entire list under the pseudoname `My Class`?

Comment: One option is to write a custom command which parses the csv file adds 'CC' entries for all the recipients, so that they do not see other recipients

Comment: Correction: I meant 'BCC'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this. Reading your question I see two main requirements

1) Parsing a csv file and getting the list of emails from it

2) Sending out emails to the list of emails retrieved without recipients seeing other recipients email address

For first requirement I would suggest you to use [pcsv](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-pcsv). Below is an example of of using the library

```el
(require 'pcsv)

(defun my-get-emails-from-csv (file &optional file-has-header-p)
  (let* ((csv (pcsv-parse-file file))
         ;; If csv file has header strip the first element of the list
         (emails (if file-has-header-p (cdr csv) csv)))
    ;; Go through the csv entries and format them for mu4e
    (mapcar (lambda (email) (format "%s <%s>"
                                    ;; Remove any , in names
                                    (replace-regexp-in-string "," "" (cadr email))
                                    (car email)))
            emails)))
```

The above function will parse the given file and return a list of emails of the format `user <email>`.

Using this you can define an mail abbrev using `define-mail-abbrev` like so

```el
(define-mail-abbrev "MyClass" (string-join (my-get-emails-from-csv "<path-to-csv>" t) ", "))
```

For the second requirement you will have to use the [`BCC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy) header. Please also note that [**most**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy#Visibility) (not all) email implementations hide the recipients so please research before using this.

In `mu4e` while composing a message you can do <kbd>M-x</kbd>`mail-bcc`<kbd>RET</kbd> this will add a `bcc` header, you can type your alias `MyClass` and hit <kbd>SPC</kbd> and it will be expanded to the aliased entries. You might also want to add yourself to the `To:` field.

Since you have the basic building blocks, you can define custom commands that do what you want, one such example is below, it reads the path to a `csv` file (it assumes file is in the format specified in your question) from the user and inserts the emails from the file in the `BCC` field.

```el
(defun my-mail-to-people-from-file (file)
  (interactive "fRead emails from file: ")
  (save-excursion
    (mail-bcc)
    ;; Read the emails from the CSV file and insert them
    (insert (string-join (my-get-emails-from-csv file t) ", "))))
```

In case string-join is not defined in your emacs use following to define it

```el
(unless (fboundp 'string-join)
  (defun string-join (strings &optional separator)
    "Join all STRINGS using SEPARATOR."
    (mapconcat 'identity strings separator)))
```

Comment: This looks great! One problem--putting this in my .emacs returns "Warining (initialization): An error occurred while loading `.emacs`: Symbol's function definition is void: `string-join`

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick It seems you are using an older version of emacs, `string-join` was added in emacs 24.4, I have updated the answer to handle this case

Comment: What a great answer! Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Your are welcome, glad I could help!

Comment: @Iqbai I thought I awarded you the bounty days ago, but I guess I was mistaken. Thanks again for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no built-in feature in `mu4e` to achieve this.  However, `message-mode` does support mail aliases.

The procedure `(define-mail-abbrev NAME DEFINITION &optional FROM-MAILRC-FILE)` could be used to define a name "My Class" that expands to the result of parsing the CSV file into a comma-separated list of strings.  When composing a message, type "My Class" and run `M-x expand-abbrev` to expand the mail alias.

The part that takes some effort is to parse the CSV file.  You also need to remember to do re-evaluate the procedure that creates the abbreviation from the result of parsing the CSV.